# Logic app when a blob is added or modified for all containers

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Is there any way of triggering logic app on adding files or modification for all containers in a blob storage? I know that I can do that for specific one using When blob is added or modified trigger:

[image]

But is it doable for all containers using one logic app?

Comment: No, my suggestion is have an individual logic app for all containers and route each of those into an app that does all of the shared work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do agree with @skin you cannot do for all containers in logic app workflow using `when a blob is added or modified`:

But I would suggest you to use Event Grid Trigger In Logic app, where more than one event can be used as below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Here I have used Consumption plan and it got triggerred in both containers, so you can use this.

Here in BlobUrl you can get the name of the blob.

Here more than one event type is used.

If you are using `when a blob is added or modified` you can use @skin's comment to use app which is usefull.

Comment: thanks you, this component does the job, can you point a component to trigger file download action?